# Error 1053:The service did not respond to start or control request in timely fashion with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, infinite-loop, filesystemwatcher

I have created a Windows Service which uses a FileSystemWatcher to look for changes in different directories. When I launch the service I am getting the error:

```
Error 1053:The service did not respond to start or control request in timely fashion.
```

I think that the error is coming from an infinite loop caused by using the `using` statement in the Watch() method as shown below:

```
    public FileSystemWatcher Watch()
    {

        FileSystemWatcher watcher;
        using (watcher = new FileSystemWatcher($"C:\\Users\\lashi\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 3", _ext))
        {
           
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            watcher.Created += OnChanged;
            watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
            watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        }
        return watcher;
    }
```

This is my OnStart() method:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        String userName;
        String expt;
        if (args.Length < 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"FileWatcher <user> <exptName>");
            Console.WriteLine($"Captures files into /temp/<exptName>-log and /temp/<exptName>-files");
            userName = "wost";
            expt = "expt1";
        }
        else
        {
            userName = args[0];
            expt = args[1];
        }
        String lexpt = $"C:\\Users\\lashi\\Desktop\\EMMC_CACHE\\{expt}-log";
        String fexpt = $"C:\\Users\\lashi\\Desktop\\EMMC_CACHE\\{expt}-file";

        if (!Directory.Exists(fexpt))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(fexpt);
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(lexpt))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(lexpt);
        }
        // File Watcher Launch
        Watcher w = new Watcher(lexpt, fexpt, userName);
        FileSystemWatcher fw = w.Watch();
    }
```

Can you please help me to find a solution to this issue? I have tried a lot of suggestions but they don't seem to work. Thank you!

Comment: have you installed the service in your computer? If so, you could try to use try catch to achieve the exception. Then, you can write it into log.txt file. Then you can know where is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Click [here](https://knowledge.kofax.com/Capture/Kofax_Capture/Services/Increase_Windows_service_timeout_to_prevent_Error_1053_The_service_did_not_respond_to_the_start_or_control_request_in_a_timely_fashion)! to see how to increase Windows services pipe timeout by editing the registry keys